# C# 4.0 Optional Parameters - How to Specify Optional Parameter of Type "Guid"?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, guid, optional-parameters

Here's my method:

```
public void SomeQuery(string email = "", Guid userId = Guid.Empty)
{
   // do some query
}
```

`userId` is giving me an error as it must be a compile-time constant, which i understand. But even when i declare a const:

```
private const emptyGuid = Guid.Empty;
```

then change the method signature to:

```
public void SomeQuery(string email = "", Guid userId = emptyGuid)
{
   // do some query
}
```

still no love.

What am i missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I default a parameter to Guid.Empty in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117970/how-can-i-default-a-parameter-to-guid-empty-in-c)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried setting it to a new instance of `Guid` ala:

```
public void SomeQuery(string email = "", Guid userId = new Guid())
{
   // do some query
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The good thing about this approach is that you can still test for it using Guid.Empty in your code. e.g.

if(userId == Guid.Empty) { ... }

Comment: @Bennor - i was juuuuust about to write some unit tests for that exact scenario. Thanks for saving me some time! =)

Comment: You should avoid optional parameters when possible.  They're a code smell.  Also, they encourage bad API's by making encapsulation much harder, and by encouraging different behaviors to be implemented by the same method.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a better solution be to overload the method with a version that doesn't require the Guid?  This would solve the issue, and would be a better design in my opinion.  Of course, there may be other constraints that I am unaware of necessitating this design.

Comment: The whole point of C# 4 Optional Parameters is to avoid unecessary overloading.

I have around 7 parameters that i'm filtering by (in a LINQ query), why overload a method 7 times with the same code? I guess that's the 'other constraints' your referring to. =)

Comment: for 2 arguments is better to have 2 overloaded methods than optional parametrs IMO. Mainly it is for design like mySuperObject.Add( ref one, ref two, ref three, ref four, ref five) vs mySuperObject.Add();

Answer (score 2):

maybe it would help (using operator ?? and Guid nullable type)

```
public void some_method(string name, Guid? guid = null)
{
        _name = name;
        _guid = guid ?? Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

Comment: hi, if i try this i get a message (roughly translated): A value of Type '<null>' kann not be used as standard parameter, becuse there is no standardconversion to "System.Guid'