# How can I default a parameter to Guid.Empty in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

I wish to say:

```
public void Problem(Guid optional = Guid.Empty)
{
}
```

But the compiler complains that Guid.Empty is not a compile time constant.

As I don’t wish to change the API I can’t use:

```
 Nullable<Guid>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# 4.0: Can I use a TimeSpan as an optional parameter with a default value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168798/c-sharp-4-0-can-i-use-a-timespan-as-an-optional-parameter-with-a-default-value)

Comment: What is wrong with switching to `Nullable<Guid> optional = null` (or more tersely, `Guid? optional = null`)? Any Guids currently passed to it will coerce without any code changes needed at all.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

### Solution

#### You can use `new Guid()` instead

```
public void Problem(Guid optional = new Guid())
{
  // when called without parameters this will be true
  var guidIsEmpty = optional == Guid.Empty;
}
```

#### You can also use `default(Guid)`

`default(Guid)` also will work exactly as `new Guid()`.

Because Guid is a value type not reference type, so, `default(Guid)` is not equal to `null` for example, instead, it's equal to calling default constructor.

Which means that this:

```
public void Problem(Guid optional = default(Guid))
{
  // when called without parameters this will be true
  var guidIsEmpty = optional == Guid.Empty;
}
```

It's exactly the same as the original example.

### Explanation

#### Why didn't `Guid.Empty` work?

The reason you are getting the error is because `Empty` is defined as:

```
public static readonly Guid Empty;
```

So, it is a variable, not a constant (defined as `static readonly` not as `const`). Compiler can only have compiler-known values as method parameters default values (not runtime-only-known).

The root cause is that you cannot have a `const` of any `struct`, unlike `enum` for example. If you try it, it will not compile.

The reason once more is that `struct` is not a primitive type.
For a list of all primitive types in .NET see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.typecode.aspx
(note that `enum` usually inherits `int`, which is a primitive)

#### But `new Guid()` is not a constant too!

I'm not saying it needs a constant. It needs something that can be decided in compile time. `Empty` is a field, so, it's value is not known in compile time (only at very beginning of run time).

Default parameter value must be known at compile-time, which may be a  `const` value, or something defined using a C# feature that makes value known at compile time, like `default(Guid)` or `new Guid()` (which is decided at compile time for `struct`s as you cannot modify the `struct` constructor in code).

While you can provide `default` or `new` easily, you cannot provide a `const` (because it's not a primitive type or an `enum` as explained above). So, again, not saying that optional parameter itself needs a constant, but compiler known value.

Comment: Well, it doesn't need a normal constant expression - `new Guid()` isn't a constant expression, for example. The C# spec defines quite clearly what's allowed, *including* but not limited to constants. (Just to be clear, it effectively *is* a compile time constant, just not a "constant expression" in C# spec terms).

Comment: Read the part **Explanation** in my reply. Added to answer this part.

Comment: You can use only `default` nowadays :)

Answer (score 151):

`Guid.Empty` is equivalent to `new Guid()`, which is equivalent to `default(Guid)`. So you can use:

```
public void Problem(Guid optional = default(Guid))
```

or

```
public void Problem(Guid optional = new Guid())
```

Note that the `new Foo()` value is *only* applicable when:

- You're really calling the *parameterless* constructor
- `Foo` is a value type

In other words, when the compiler knows it's really just the default value for the type :)

(Interestingly, I'm 99.9% sure it *won't* call any custom `new Foo()` constructor you may have created. You can't create such a constructor in a value type in C#, but you *can* do so in IL.)

You can use the `default(Foo)` option for *any* type.

Comment: Now why does the compiler error message not tell me this, the complier could check for the case of Guid.Empty and give a more helpfull message.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose: I don't think the compiler should have type-specific messages in general, to be honest.

Comment: Setting a parameter to default to a new object creates a new object every time the method is called in PHP; but only creates one object for the *entire program* in Python.  Really, I consider this to be one of the [very few design flaws of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146329/what-is-the-worst-gotcha-youve-experienced/147877#147877).  I'm somewhat glad C# (and VB.Net) avoided this issue by simply disallowing new objects in default parameters... though there are times where this ability is really nice in PHP.

Comment: what could be the reason that this same thing wouldn't work in ASP.NET MVC controller action? All other optional parameters work (int, string) but it doesn't work for GUID, says "Server Error in '/' Application. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'categoryId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' .." The code compiles fine with both specifications (default(Guid) and with new Guid()) but issues this error.

Comment: @mare: I don't know, I'm afraid. Another option would be to use `Nullable<Guid>`, potentially.

Answer (score 18):

Can't you use:

`default ( Guid )`  ?

Comment: No.  `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Guid' and 'System.Guid'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean ?? as an operator but as an emphasised question mark - I'll edit!

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer does not work in ASP.NET MVC, and cause this run-time error:

```
[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'optional' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Problem(System.Guid)' ....
```

Instead, you may do the following:

```
public void Problem(Guid? optional)
{
    if (optional == null)
    {
        optional = new Guid();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the reason for down-voting: The question specifies that API cannot be changed to use  Nullable<Guid> - fair enough

Comment: Unless you want to explicitly assign the paramter "optional" with an empty Guid value, I think this is the most natural way for defining an optional parameter of type Guid.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is quite correct; `Guid.Empty` is not a compile-time constant. You can try making a method overload like this:

```
public void Problem()
{
    Problem(Guid.Empty);
}
```

Comment: I said I did not wish to change the API, the method I am trying to tame has overe 10 parms!

Comment: @Ian Ringrose, though I agree with `Guid x = default(Guid)` as the solution, remember that adding another function overload doesn't complicated the API any more than adding an optional argument. That's really what an optional argument does anyway.

Comment: @tenfour, it would have to be **many** new function overloads to do the same as 10 optional parms!

Comment: If you have a public function that requires over ten parameters, maybe making a single argument optional isn't really a fix... Also, looking back at the original question, you do indeed say that you don't want to "change the API" (and like tenfour points out, the difference between an explicit overload and an optional argument is minimal in practice) but there is no mention in the question of the parameter list being that kind of a monster.

Comment: Actually, this is a perfect answer to the problem.